# Eclipse DDMS Network Statistics empty

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

I once had this working but now the DDMS networks tab is completely empty. I tried 3 different devices (one even rooted), they have an ADB connection, everything else works. No luck. 
What could I be missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a problem in SDK tools revision 22,

Download the [new revision 22.0.1](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html)

> Fixed a problem with DDMS monitor not opening heap and network statistics views due to a class not found exception. (Issue 55394)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem although I had 22.0.1 rev.
**it solved by updating the version**:
window-> check for updates